# Does distcp in hadoop ENCRYPT data while transporting from one cluster to another

Tags: hadoop, encryption, distcp, secure-transport, bigdata

I would like to know whether distcp has option to encrypt data while transporting from one cluster to another. I got to know that it does support encryption in S3 cluster but that is something to do with amazon's S3. What if we are moving plain text file from one cluster to another. Will it be encrypted or plain text is sent ?  Can we enable such encryption, if it supports?

Answer (score 1):

From HDFS [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/TransparentEncryption.html#Configuration):

> Once a KMS has been set up and the NameNode and HDFS clients have been
> correctly configured, an admin can use the hadoop key and hdfs crypto
> command-line tools to create encryption keys and set up new encryption
> zones. Existing data can be encrypted by copying it into the new
> encryption zones using tools like distcp.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think that answers the question. If I understand that correctly, the data being transferred is not encrypted until it reaches the encryption zone